# Application of Banach -Steinhaus in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

This is the problem:

Let $(H,(\cdot,\cdot))$ be a  real Hilbert space and let $\{ e_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of orthogonal vectors such that  for $i \neq j$ $(e_i,e_j)=0$ , where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the scalar product in $H$. Assume that $\forall x \in  H$ we have that the limit

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{h=1}^{n}(x,e_h)e_h$

exists (i.e is an element of $H$) . Prove that

$sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ||e_n||_H$ $ < \infty$

where $|| \cdot||_H$ denotes the norm in $H$.

I am having trouble with this exercise just for the "easy "part I think.My idea was to consider the sequence of operators in dual space $\phi_n(x) \, \colon H \to H $ defined as

$\phi_n(x) = (x,e_n)$.

It is indeed easy to see that,if $H'$ is the dual space, $||\phi_n||_{H'} = ||e_n||_{H}$ by schwartz inequality: So, I thought to apply the uniform boundeness principle to this operator, maybe using orthogonality and the existance of the limit in the hypotesis, but I failed in that as I could not prove that my family of operators satisfied the hypotesis of the theorem. In details I could not prove:

$ \forall x \in H \exists C \in \mathbb{R} \, , C=C(x) $ such that

$sup_{n \in N}||\phi_n(x)||_H \leq C(x)$

I would need a hint to use properly the uniform boundeness principle but even a total solution  would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the sequence of operators in dual space $\phi_n(x) \, \colon H \to H $ defined as $\phi_n(x) = (x,e_n)e_n$.  They are clearly continuous linear transformations from $H$ to $H$.

Define $\forall x \in  H$, 
$$T(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{h=1}^{n}(x,e_h)e_h $$

Since $\forall x \in  H$ we have that the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{h=1}^{n}(x,e_h)e_h$ exists (i.e is an element of $H$), we have that  $\forall x \in  H$, $T(x)$ is well-defined and 
$$ \|T(x)\|_H < + \infty$$

Take $C(x)= \|T(x)\|_H$. Its easy to see that, for all $n$, 
$$ |\phi_n(x)| = \|(x,e_n)e_n\|_H\leq \|T(x)\|_H =C(x)$$

(Remark: We used the orthogonality of the sequence $\{ e_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, to conclude that, for all $n$, $ \|(x,e_n)e_n\|_H\leq \|T(x)\|_H $)

So, by the Uniform Boundness Principle, you have:

$$sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|\phi_n\| < \infty$$

that is

$$sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|e_n\|_{H}^2< \infty$$

that is

$$sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|e_n\|_{H} < \infty$$

Comment: Do you ever use vector orthogonality? if so , where ? If you do not-as it seems-  do you think it is a non necessary assumption?

Comment: @GiuseppeTenaglia I used the orthogonality. I updated the answer to make it clear where I used it.

Comment: Thanks so much I did not see that so clearly